# Custom attribute in address page

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I want to add the custom attribute like Landmark, Address type, Locality etc on address page in Magento 2.1.12.

Please suggest me the better way to achieve this.

Comment: Check this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Answer (score 0):

Create Customer address attribute using installdata script as below:

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'landmark', [
     'label' => 'Landmark',
     'input' => 'text',
     'type' => 'varchar',
     'source' => '',
     'required' => true,
     'position' => 70,
     'visible' => true,
     'system' => false,
     'is_used_in_grid' => false,
     'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
     'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
     'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
     'backend' => ''
 ]);


 $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'suburb')
     ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
         'adminhtml_customer_address',
         'customer_address_edit',
         'customer_register_address'
     ]]);
 $attribute->save();`
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom attribute you can create a new module. Assume it's called Custom. Now you can follow these steps :

**1** Create **di.xml** file under

> **app/code/Vendor/Custom/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="add_custom_field_checkout_form" type="Custom\Module\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
</type>
```

**2** After that you should create a plugin class on this Directory

> **app/code/Vendor/Custom/Model/Plugin/Checkout**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Custom\Plugin\Checkout;
 class LayoutProcessor
 {
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'custom-field'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field',
        'label' => 'Custom Field',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 250,
        'id' => 'custom-field'
    ];


    return $jsLayout;
 }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Good luck !!!